# ksh perl script.. if condition

Tags: perl, ksh

Friends...

I have got bash script which calls perl script and emails logfile result everytime.

I want to change my bash script such that it should only email if there is value in perl subroutine row counter (rcounter++) and not all time.

any tips on how to change .ksh file?

```
.ksh

#!/bin/ksh
d=`date +%Y%m%d`

log_dir=$HOME
output_file=log.list

if ! list_tables -login /@testdb -outputFile $output_file
   then    
      mailx -s "list report : $d" test@mail < $output_file
 fi

=======Below if condition also works for me=============================

  list_tables -login /@testdb -outputFile $output_file
 if ["$?" -ne "0"];
    then    
          mailx -s "list report : $d" test@mail < $output_file
 fi
========================================================================
```

Perl Script: list_tables

```
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

use DBI;
use DBD::Oracle qw(:ora_types);

my $exitStatus = 0;
my %options = ()
my $oracleLogin;
my $outputFile;
my $runDate;
my $logFile;
my $rcounter;

($oracleLogin, $outputFile) = &validateCommandLine();

my $db = &attemptconnect($oracleLogin);

&reportListTables($outputFile);

$db->$disconnect;

exit($rcounter);


#---------------------------
sub reportListTables {

    my $outputFile = shift;

    if ( ! open (OUT,">" . $outputfile)) {
        &logMessage("Error opening $outputFile");
    }

    print OUT &putTitle;

    my $oldDB="DEFAULT";
    my $dbcounter = 0;
    my $i;

    print OUT &putHeader();

    #iterate over results
    for (my $i=0; $i<=$lstSessions; $i++) {
        # print result row
        print OUT &putRow($i);
        $dbCounter++;
    }

    print OUT &putFooter($dbCounter);
    print OUT "   *** Report End \n";

    closeOUT;
}


#------------------------------ 
sub putTitle {
    my $title = qq{
   List Tables: Yesterday
  --------------
};


#------------------------------
sub putHeader {
    my $header = qq{

   TESTDB
  ==============
    OWNER       Table   Created


};

#------------------------------
sub putRow {

    my $indx = shift;
    my $ln = sprintf "%-19s %-30s %-19s",
       $lstSessions[$indx]{owner},
       $lstSessions[$indx]{object_name},
       $lstSessions[$indx]{created};

return "$ln\n";

}

#------------------------------
sub getListTables {

    my $runDt = shift;
       $rcounter = 0;

    my $SQL = qq{
    selct owner, object_name, to_char(created,'MM-DD-YYYY') from dba_objects
    };

    my $sth = $db->prepare ($SQL) or die $db->errstr;

    $sth->execute() or die $db->errstr;;

    while (my @row = $sth->fethcrow_array) {
        $lstSessions[$rcounter] {owner}     =$row[0];
        $lstSessions[$rcounter] {object_name}   =$row[1];
        $lstSessions[$rcounter] {created}   =$row[2];

        &logMessage(" Owner:    $lstSessions[$rcounter]{owner}");
        &logMessage(" Table:    $lstSessions[$rcounter]{object_name}");
        &logMessage(" created:  $lstSessions[$rcounter]{created}");

        $rcounter++;
    }

    &logMessage("$rcounter records found...");

}
```

thanks..

also happy to include mail-x part in perl if that makes life more easy..

Comment: You forgot to interpolate variables `$SQL` and `$rcounter` (used bareword `SQL` and string `rcounter` instead), and you declared `$rounter` but used `$rcounter`. Using a global variable `@lstSessions` is most likely a very bad idea. Use `use strict; use warnings;`, and fix the resulting warnings/errors.

Comment: thanks TLP for your comments...actaully I have used $SQL, $rcounter, strict and warning in original code... this was typo here since I didn't copy paste code...  any idea how to only email via .ksh if there is a value in record counter?

Comment: I presume that `list_tables` is the name of your Perl script, but you don't actually say so. Why not just put all the logic into the Perl script? If the Perl script used elsewhere, perhaps you could add an option that tells it to invoke `mailx` appropriately.

Comment: done put all logic and file name as suggested...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understood your question correctly. Also, your code is incomplete. So there's some guessing involved.

---

You *cannot* check the value of a local Perl variable from the caller's side.

But if your question is if the Perl code added anything to the logfile, the solution is simple: Delete the "rcounter records found..." line (which doesn't make sense anyway since it is *always* executed, whether the query returned results or not). Then, let the shell script backup the logfile before the call to Perl, and make a `diff` afterwards, sending the mail only if `diff` tells you there has been output added to the logfile.

If this doesn't help you, please clarify the question.

**EDIT** (from comments below):

Shell scripting isn't that difficult. Right now, your Perl script ends with:

```
$db->($exitStatus);
```

That is your exit code. You don't check that in your shell script anyway, so you could change it to something more useful, like the number of data rows written. A primitive solution would be to make `$rcounter` global (instead of local to `getListTables()`), by declaring it at the top of the Perl script (e.g. after `my $logFile;`). Then you could replace the "exitStatus" line above with simply:

```
$rcounter;
```

Voila, your Perl script now returns the number of data rows written.

In Perl, a return code of 0 is considered a failure, any other value is a success. In shell, it's the other way around - but luckily you don't have to worry about that as Perl knows that and "inverts" (negates) the return code of a script when returning to the calling shell.

So all you need is making the mailing depend on a non-zero return of Perl:

```
if list_tables -login /@testdb -outputFile $output_file
then
    mailx -s "list report : $d" test@mail < $output_file
fi
```

A comment on the side: It looks to me as if your programming skill isn't up to par with the scope of the problem you are trying to solve. If returning a value from Perl to bash gives you that much trouble, you should probably spend your time with tutorials, not with getting input from a database and sending emails around. Learn to walk before you try to fly...

Comment: Dev... yes I was trying to check variable rcounter from subroutine which you said can't check from caller... basically my output file gets contents from 3-4 different subroutine (header, footer) so trying to email output file if any tables were created which I query from $SQL.

Comment: @Khallas301: I am still not sure I understand. *cough* English *cough*... You could make your Perl script exit with an appropriate return code (send mail / don't send mail), which you could check in the shell script (variable `$?`). If that doesn't work for some reason, you could make the Perl script generate a "trigger file", and your shell script checks for the existence of the trigger file (`if [ -f ${triggerfile} ]; then mailx ...; fi`). Don't forget to delete the trigger file afterwards.

Comment: please excuse my English since it's not my first language also I was commenting in real hurry which makes sentence more complex to understand ;) ... whole idea of this perl script is simple ... 1. query db and get output in logfile 2. Have logfile formatted properly (header/footer) 3. call perl file from .ksh and email output logfile...... my current challenge is only email output logfile if step 1 has any row....

Comment: @Khallas301: English isn't my first language either. And did my previous comment help you with your problem, or is something still unclear?

Comment: Dev..sorry for the late reply, just lost track with this thread. I did understood your suggestion but honestly shell scripting is too complex for me and I just wanted to keep it simple without involving diff because future plan is to separate output file as per day of the week. If calling perl variable not an option then will go with including email part in perl script.

Comment: @Khallas301: It would be *very* easy to show you how to do it. Unfortunately, your "code example" is completely broken (e.g., your core function `getListTables()` doesn't even get **called**, so it's hard to show you which changes would be necessary to make it **return** something meaningful...)

Comment: yes you are right my perl or even programming skill is not upto par but sometimes you don't have a choice and have to Just do it.. I will test and update result here... I like that punch line "Learn to Walk before you Fly" it has a kick..

Comment: dev I tried your suggested changes but looks like still I'm missing something silly... I have updated script in original post but currently it's working other way around... shell script emails if there are no row but if exit status ($rcounter) has any row then it doesn't emails.

Comment: @Khallas301: Negate. `if ! list_tables ...`. Or omit the `exit()` (which you didn't use in your original code, which is why my solution "suddenly" breaks when you added it).

Comment: dev... thanks a lot.. finally it's working only thing missing was "!" .. I was also testing another way and it also worked for me.. no idea any negative effects of that (edited original code with both change)

Comment: @Khallas301: Checking the return code like that (`"$?" -ne "0"`)  is the same thing as `if ! list_tables`, just more verbose. However, there is a small snatch: **Semantically**, you want to check for the **success** of `list_tables`. A success is a non-zero `$rcounter`. Ending your Perl script with just `$rcounter;` would have the desired result, and you could omit the "!" in shell. However, you use `$rcounter` as parameter for `exit()`, *which works the other way around*: Here, **zero** means "success", and that is why the shell script has to do one additional (semantically wrong) negation.

Comment: dev.. WOW you got me thinking again...thanks for this wonderful explanation.. will also test suggested way...